# How to link multiple github account to one heroku account?

Tags: heroku, github

I have read the documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration#enabling-github-integration but it does not state how to link more than one github account to a single heroku account.

We can see clearly that there is a **dropdown list** next to the github username so, I am assuming this is possible. 
[image]

Otherwise, what's the point of this dropdown menu if I only have one github account per heroku account?

Comment: I think the dropdown may be to access organizations that you belong to.

Comment: Did you found a solution to link another account, or have more than one?

Answer (score 1):

No, Its not possible to link multiple git account to one single heroku accounts, if you have a situation , you can switch between heroku accounts or you can maintain repos in a single github account that is linked with your heroku account. 
Read the link for more info : https://help.heroku.com/5S1JZYSQ/can-i-use-multiple-github-accounts